# Angular 2 with TypeScript and Input decorator generate bad javascript ids

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, typescript1.8

Hello guys,

I'm learning angular2 with Typescript and developing a new example I found some weird behaviour that maybe you can explain.

**TypeScript Version:** 
1.8.10

**Angular Version:** 
2.0.0-rc.1

**Code**

When I'm adding the @Input to a field, the generated js has errors in the generated ids:

This is the Typescript class I'm working on:

```ts
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Event } from '../../model/event';
    import { EventService } from '../../services/event-service';

    @Component({
      selector: "event-detail",
      templateUrl: "event-detail.html",
      providers: [EventService],
      moduleId: module.id
    })
    export class EventDetailComponent {
        @Input()
        event: Event;
        eventTypes : string[];

        constructor(private service: EventService){
        }

        ngOnInit(){
          this.loadEventTypes();
        }

        save(){
          this.service.create(this.event).then(
            event => this.event = event
          );
        }

        cancel(){
          this.event = null;
        }

        loadEventTypes(){
          let response = this.service.listEventTypes()
            .then(eventTypes => this.eventTypes = eventTypes);
        }
    }
```

And this is the error:

[image]

The following javascript code generated by the compiler is throwing the error because the event_1 doesn't exist.

```ts
__decorate([
  core_1.Input(),
  __metadata('design:type', event_1.Event)
], EventDetailComponent.prototype, "event", void 0);
```

Do you know what could be happen? Could a configuration be in conflict?

Comment: I'm looking over this, but I've had trouble calling a class Event before _edit_ also event_1 is most likely a generated namespace, not element. Input() defines a HTML property that can be used in the template as input to the component _edit2_ this looks like an import issue

Comment: I fount something interesting, if I assign a default value to event attribute like `@Input() event: Event = new EventImpl();` then the component works! So is required to init every @Input variable?

Comment: no it's not, does EventImpl inherit from Event? you should import all of these modules

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not load '../../model/event' module (perhaps it contains error, wrong path etc.).

Comment: The Event class is imported fine in the 2nd line `import { Event } from '../../model/event';`

Comment: import statement is required but it does not guarantee that everything works. can you provide event module source code? what is directory structure, do you have errors in network tab?